# trying to have a bot move randomly on a xz pane with Threejs

Tags: javascript, three.js

I started out with following code which creates a block that moves on a straight line:

```
const bot_geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry(1,1,1);
const bot_material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( {color: 0x7777ff, wireframe:   false} );
const bot = new THREE.Mesh( bot_geometry, bot_material );

bot.position.x = 1;
bot.position.y = 0;
bot.position.z = 1;
scene.add(bot);

//create random directions for bot
let direction = new THREE.Vector3(0.001, 0, 0.002); // amount to move per frame

    function animate() {
              bot.position.add(direction); // add to position
              requestAnimationFrame(animate); // keep looping
            }
requestAnimationFrame(animate);
```

I am trying to make it move randomly on the plane and tried to use following two lines for the direction but now I have two blocks moving on a straight line opposite from each other. Is there a simple way to have one bot move randomly on the plane?:

```
let reverseDirection = Math.floor(Math.random()*2) == 1 ? 1 : -1; 
let direction = new THREE.Vector3(0.001*reverseDirection, 0, 0.002*reverseDirection);
```

Answer (score 1):

you can set random direction like this

```
direction = new THREE.Vector3(Math.random() * 2 - 1, 0, Math.random() * 2 - 1).normalize();
```

also, you can set global variables

```
var direction;
var speed = 5; // units per second
var clock = new THREE.Clock();
var delta;
var shift = new THREE.Vector3();
```

and in your animation loop

```
delta = clock.getDelta();
shift.copy(direction).multiplyScalar(delta * speed);
bot.position.add(shift);
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/prisoner849/qqoouo2w/) example

Comment: `clone()` calls `new`. Avoid calling `clone()` or `new` in the animation loop unnecessarily.